# Conditional Parameter/Method Signatures in c#?

Tags: c#

I know, how to do conditional parameters in methods, etc. The problem I have is this: I have inherited an old (but working) class library (which I'm not allowed to touch). In it is a method, let's call it `oldmethod(string, string, string)` that has an override `oldmethod(string, string, string, string)`.

I cannot submit an empty string, because it throws an exception. I know, I can do an if-else and check my parameters and then call the signature I want, but is there an easier, inline way?

Is there some way to call the method with a conditional signature, e.g. if one of the strings is empty use the three parameter signature, if none is empty use the four parameter one?

Comment: read on about adapter pattern

Comment: A method with four parameters *cannot* override a method with three parameters, so your description doesn't make sense. Please clarify the question, ideally with a [mcve].

Comment: `void somemethod(string a1, string a2, string a3)  
{... some code... }  
void somemethod(string a1, string a2, string a3, string a4)
{...some code...}`

Comment: @Thangadurai, thanks, yes I know. It just would be nice to be able to not have to wrap it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears there is no other way. Thank you all for your suggestions. `If...then...else` works of course, and so does a wrapper or an extension. In the end I used an inline `if..then` similar to Patrick's suggestion.

But that's a workaround. Not an answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to let the compiler pick one method over the other based on runtime values. You can however make this yourself quite easily.

Just create an intermediate method where you check what method to call:

```
public void NewMethod(string s1, string s2, string s3, string s4)
{
    string[] nonEmpty = new string[] { s1, s2, s3, s4 }.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToArray();
    if (nonEmpty.Length == 4)
    {
        oldmethod(s1, s2, s3, s4);
    }
    else if (nonEmpty.Length == 3)
    {
        oldmethod(s1, s2, s3);
    }
    else
    {
        // unexpected, fix or throw
    }
}
```

Comment: no offense.. but this is what the OP has to say `I know, I can do an if-else and check my parameters and then call the signature I want, but is there an easier, inline way?`

Comment: Also since the order of the parameter will not change isn't it enough if you just do a `string.IsNullOrEmpty(s4)` in the if directly ?

Comment: @RajshekarReddy The answer is `No`, which is in the first few words. Then I give a solution that minimizes the number of `if..else` statements to 1. And yes, that can be possible, depending on the needs of OP.

Comment: @RajshekarReddy, yes, that's the if..then..else way. I can do that inline, too.... do a boolean to check each value for null, and then do a ?: switch calling the first signature if one is null, and the second if not. That is a way around it. I was more interested to find out if there was another way.

Comment: @ToshiBoy it is the only way. You can anyways write extensions or use concept of reflections and get this working with a single line of code, But still even with that approach you are just simplifying the code usage and end up with a if else behind the scenes.